# Merging Objects throws TargetException in C#

Tags: c#, merge

I am merging two arbitrary objects like this:

```
public void MergeWorkSpaceObjs<T>(T source, T target)
{
    Type t = typeof(T);
    var properties = t.GetProperties().Where(prop =>
                                                prop != null &&
                                                prop.CanRead &&
                                                prop.CanWrite);
    foreach (var prop in properties)
    {
        var value = prop.GetValue(source);
        if (value != null)
        {
            prop.SetValue(target, value);
        }
    }

    var fields = t.GetFields();
    foreach (var fi in fields)
    {
        var targetField = t.GetField(fi.Name);
        targetField.SetValue(target, fi.GetValue(source));
    }
}
```

When I call the method, I get this error:

```
Test Name:  SaveConfigs
Test FullName:  Automata.Tests.WorkSpaceTest.SaveConfigs
Test Source:    E:\Programming\C#\Automata\Automata.Tests\WorkSpaceTests.cs : line 47
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00.014

Result StackTrace:  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(Object target)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)
   at Automata.WorkSpace.MergeObjs[T](T source, T target) in E:\Programming\C#\Automata\Automata\WorkSpace.cs:line 156
   at Automata.WorkSpace.Save() in E:\Programming\C#\Automata\Automata\WorkSpace.cs:line 130
   at Automata.Tests.WorkSpaceTest.SaveConfigs() in E:\Programming\C#\Automata\Automata.Tests\WorkSpaceTests.cs:line 48
Result Message: System.Reflection.TargetException : Non-static method requires a target.
```

I'm not sure what that error means entirely. After some Googling, it looks like the error is related to a missing class instantiation or there is a null property, but I'm not sure where, I'm still new to C#.

What does that error mean and how can I resolve it?

Comment: How do you call this function? it looks like `source` is `null`

Comment: @OfirWinegarten I call it when trying to merge a configuration from a file when saving the configuration. Here it is in context: https://gist.github.com/mxplusb/4ba939928805387a427f88d005be38aa#file-workspace-cs-L123

Comment: And are you sure that `userConfig` is not `null`? debug and see